# Pivot Data for Graphing

Tags: javascript, sorting, charts, pivot, transpose

This may be a very basic question, but I am not very familiar with JS and trying to teach myself on the fly for a PCR project at work and would love some help.

I have a Javascript array formatted as

```
//[well, cycle, result]//
[1, 1, -4778],
[1, 2, -4066],
[1, 3, -3647],
[1, 4, -3111],
[1, 5, -2861],
[2, 1, -3655],
[2, 2, -2948],
[2, 3, -2665],
[2, 4, -2289],
[2, 5, -2126],
```

There is a total of 16 wells and 35 cycles per well. I need to pivot or reformat the data so that I can correctly graph it using google core charts. The chart requires the data be input as

```
//[cycle, Result(well1), Result(well2), etc...]//
[1, -4778, -3655, etc..]
[2, -4066, -2948, etc..]
```

I have an attempt at doing this on a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mmoore/4azou18t/). Please excuse the messy fiddle, I've been messing around in it trying to figure stuff out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is not a badly written question, but it doesn't follow one important convention.   Please include relevant code in the question itself.  You can link to  a more complete case at something like JSFiddle, but the question should stand alone if that link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by `reduce`ing the array and gathering the results per cycle together in a cycle-keyed, results-array-valued object, and then combining the keys and values into a single object when they're all gathered:

```js
const pivot = (input) => Object .entries (input .reduce (
  (a, [well, cycle, result]) => ({...a, [cycle]: [...(a[cycle] || []), result]}),
  {}
)) .map (([cycle, results]) => [Number (cycle), ...results])

const input = [[1, 1, -4778], [1, 2, -4066], [1, 3, -3647], [1, 4, -3111], [1, 5, -2861], [2, 1, -3655], [2, 2, -2948], [2, 3, -2665], [2, 4, -2289], [2, 5, -2126]]

console .log (pivot (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

While I find that style code very clean, it is [less efficient](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) than we might prefer.  Either of these two stylistic variants of one another would do the same job more efficiently, although to my mind less elegantly:

```js
const pivot = (input) => Object .entries (input .reduce (
  (a, [well, cycle, result]) => 
    ((a [cycle] = a [cycle] || []), (a [cycle] .push (result)), a),
  {}
)) .map (([cycle, results]) => [Number (cycle), ...results])
```

or

```js
const pivot = (input) => Object .entries (input .reduce (
  (a, [well, cycle, result]) => {
    a [cycle] = a [cycle] || []
    a [cycle] .push (result)
    return a
  },
  {}
)) .map (([cycle, results]) => [Number(cycle), ...results])
```